# Get Magento option entity value based on the value's id

Tags: magento

Here is the scenario specific to a base installation of magento.
I would like to be able to change some content on my category pages when a manufacturer filter has been chosen.

What I see is 
http://www.myurl.com/path/to/cat.html?manufacturer=777

From this I can get the manufacturers id by doing something like:

```
$request->getParam('manufacturer');
```

What I would like to be able to do is jump into `eav_attribute_option_value` and get the manufacturers name based on the `value_id` (8404 in my case) and the manufacturer id to return the name of the manufacturer.

I am sure there are other use cases where this would become handy too.
For my case I will be prepending the brand to the category title tag based on some other logic. This will create new highly branded category pages that should rank well on google.

So your base category title tag might look like: 'Washing Machines'

And then the manufacturer brand filter page for Maytag would look like: 'Maytag Washing Machines'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to find a dirty way to do this.
            $query = "SELECT * FROM mg_eav_attribute_option_value WHERE option_id =" . $request_params['manufacturer'] . " LIMIT 0 , 30";
            $read = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource')->getConnection('core_read');
            $manufacturer = $read->fetchAll($query);